# The limit containing sum of arccosines DOES exist

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

I'm trying to handle a quite complicated limit involving series. Such limits are really scary for me because I do not know any technique to compute them. The initial limit is $$\lim_{m\to\infty}\left(\ln\left(m+1+\sqrt{m^2+2m}\right)+\sum_{n=1}^{m+1}\arccos\frac1n-(m+1)\arccos\frac1{m+1}\right)$$
I'm thinking that determining of asymptotic behaviour of the sum $\sum_{n=1}^m\arccos\frac1n$ as $m\to\infty$ will help to evaluate this limit. Thank you for any contribution.

**As an addition**. Maybe it could be helpful. The last two terms I got after simplifying sum $$-\sum_{n=1}^m n\left(\arccos\frac1{n+1}-\arccos\frac1n\right)$$

**Update**. The limit could be rewritten (after changing $m+1\to m$) as $$\lim_{m\to\infty}\left(\ln\left(m+\sqrt{m^2-1}\right)+\sum_{n=1}^{m}\arccos\frac1n-m\arccos\frac1{m}\right)$$ or $$\lim_{m\to\infty}\left(\operatorname{arccosh}m+\sum_{n=1}^{m}\arccos\frac1n-m\arccos\frac1{m}\right)$$
The limit seems to exist. After computing numerically it seems to tend to $\color{red}{0.508132}$.

**Update #2**. After using Euler–Maclaurin formula I've gotten that $\sum_{n=1}^m\arccos\frac1n$ could be expressed as follows (for certain $p$, $f(x)=\arccos\frac1x$):

$$\begin{aligned}\sum_{n=1}^m\arccos\frac1n&=\int_1^m\arccos\frac1x\,dx+\frac12\arccos\frac1m+\sum_{k=1}^{\lfloor p/2\rfloor}\frac{B_{2k}}{(2k)!}\left(f^{(2k-1)}(m)-f^{(2k-1)}(1)\right)+R_p\\
&=m\arccos\frac1m-\operatorname{arccosh}m+\frac12\arccos\frac1m+\sum_{k=1}^{\lfloor p/2\rfloor}\frac{B_{2k}}{(2k)!}\left(f^{(2k-1)}(m)-f^{(2k-1)}(1)\right)+R_p
\end{aligned}$$
Thus $$\sum_{n=1}^m\arccos\frac1n-m\arccos\frac1m+\operatorname{arccosh}m=\frac12\arccos\frac1m+\sum_{k=1}^{\lfloor p/2\rfloor}\frac{B_{2k}}{(2k)!}\left(f^{(2k-1)}(m)-f^{(2k-1)}(1)\right)+R_p$$ and $$\lim_{m\to\infty}\left(\operatorname{arccosh}m+\sum_{n=1}^{m}\arccos\frac1n-m\arccos\frac1{m}\right)=\lim_{m\to\infty}\left(\frac12\arccos\frac1m+\sum_{k=1}^{\lfloor p/2\rfloor}\frac{B_{2k}}{(2k)!}\left(f^{(2k-1)}(m)-f^{(2k-1)}(1)\right)+R_p\right)$$
And I'm stuck. I do not know what I can do with these Bernoulli numbers and so on.

Comment: It was a long time I calculated things like this. But maybe you can estimate this sum with integrals of some kind.

Comment: Have you tried Euler-Maclaurin formula?

Comment: No, I haven't. I supposed that it would not help because I would have to find n-th derivative of $\arccos\frac1x$ which (I think) hasn't closed form

Comment: Please have titles that reflect the content of your question, rather announcements that would only be understood after spending some nontrivial amount of time reading through your question.

Answer (score 1):

The Euler-Maclaurin formula won't help here, instead you should use Abel's summation formula, that is
$$\sum_{1 \le n \le x} a_n f(n) = f(x) A(x) - \int_1^x A(t) f'(t) \ dt,$$
where $A(x) = \sum_{1 \le n \le x} a_n$. Apply this formula with $a_n =1$ and $f(x) = \arccos(1/x)$ and get
$$\tag{1}\sum_{k=1}^{m} \arccos(1/k) = m \arccos(1/m) - \int_1^m \lfloor x \rfloor \frac{1}{x \sqrt{x^2-1}} d x.$$
Note that $\arccos(1/m) \rightarrow \pi/2$ and $x (\arccos(1/x)-\arccos(1/(x+1)) \rightarrow 0$ if $x \rightarrow \infty$.  Thus the first term on the right-side in (1) cancels with the last term in your formula.

Additionally note that $g(x) := \lfloor x \rfloor- x$ is a bounded function. Thus
$$\int_1^\infty g(x) \frac{1}{x \sqrt{x^2-1}} \, dx $$
exists as a Lebesgue-integral (i.e. is absolutely integrable). This shows that we can replace $\lfloor x \rfloor$ by $x$. Therefore we have to calculate
$$ \int_1^m \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2-1}} dx  =  \log(\sqrt{x^2-1}+x) \Big|_{x=1}^m = \log(\sqrt{m^2-1}+m).$$
We see that 
\begin{align}
&\lim_{m \rightarrow \infty} \left(\sum_{k=1}^m \arccos(1/k) - m \arccos(1/m) +\log(\sqrt{m^2-1}+m) \right) \\ &= \int_1^\infty (x - \lfloor x \rfloor) \frac{1}{x \sqrt{x^2-1}} dx.
\end{align}
Note that $\log(m+1 +\sqrt{m^2+2m}) -\log(\sqrt{m^2-1}+m) \rightarrow 0$ for $m \rightarrow \infty$.

Comment: Thank you very much for showing that wonderful technique of calculating infinite sums. But I have some doubt: don't we have to add $\log$ under the limit in the last equation?

Comment: ... you've edited typos almost everywhere. But there is one left in the last equation: $\sqrt{x^2-1}$ should be in the denominator under integral instead of $\sqrt{1-x}$

Comment: And after all... the last integral is the very on which I tried to compute in the first place :'-(

Comment: Yes, there was a sign-error! Hopefully, I have corrected all errors. :-) A similar argument can be also used in order to prove that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} ( \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k}-\ln(n))$ exists and has an integral representation. (This limes is known as the 'Euler–Mascheroni constant'.)